# Is there a paid ability window before the runner can jack out after the last subroutine executes on a piece of ice?

Tags: android-netrunner

Basically the title. A situation where this would matter. If I have a [House of Knives](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05004) scored and my opponent runs into [Kominu](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05017) with no breaker can I use the House of Knives ability after he loses all his cards but before he has a chance to jack out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, yes there is a window at 4.1 (before the runner decides to jack out after passing the last piece of ICE), or at 4.3 if the runner decides to continue.  If Komainu has another piece of ICE behind it, 2.1 also provides an opportunity for House of Knives to strike before the runner jacks out.

The run timing chart:

1. Runner starts, names server.
   If there's ICE, goto 2.
   If no ice, goto 4.
2. Approach outermost ICE.

   - **2.1. Paid ability can be used** (can be used if there is another ICE behind Komainu, and also kicks in before runner has a chance to jack out)
   - 2.2. Jack out (Goto 6, cannot jack out if first piece of ICE encountered this run) or continue to 2.3.
   - 2.3. Approached ICE can be rezzed, Paid ability can be used cards can be rezzed.
   - 2.4. Check if ICE is rezzed.
     If rezzed, goto 3.
     If unrezzed, and there's another piece of ICE, goto 2.
     If unrezzed, and there's no more ICE, go to 4.
3. Runner Encounters Ice if rezzed.

   - 3.1. Icebreakers can interact, Paid abilities can be used
   - 3.2. Resolve all unbroken subroutines
     ...Either the run ends, goto 6
     Or it continues, and there's another piece of ICE, goto 2.
     Or it continues, and there's no more ICE, go to 4.
4. Runner approaches attacked server

   - **4.1. Paid abilities can be used.**
   - 4.2. Runner decides:
     To jack out, go to 6 or to continue, go to 4.3
   - **4.3. Paid abilities may be used, cards may be rezzed.**
   - 4.4. Run is successful. Trigger abilities if any.
     4.5. Access cards. Trigger abilities if any.
     Agenda : Stolen (Unless additional cost)
     Trash cost present : may be paid to trash
     Everything not trashed or stolen is returned to server.
5. Run ends. Trigger abilities if any.
6. Run is unsuccessful. Trigger abilities if any.

Comment: If there's more ICE behind the Komainu, then the paid ability window at 2.1 should provide the opportunity to flatline the runner before he can jack out.

Comment: True, and excellent point!  2.1 is mean like that.

Comment: Oh a related question. I do not see a paid ability window before 4.4 and 5. So that means that I could not flatline the runner with House of Knives after a Psychic Field?http://netrunnerdb.com/en/card/05010

Comment: Nope, there are no paid ability windows during the run once the runner accesses.